# Disable split screen mode for android launcher

Tags: android, android-launcher, split-screen, split-screen-multitasking

I would like to exit split-screen mode when the home button is pressed on android 10.
I try a lot of solutions like setting android:resizeableActivity="false" in the manifest of my launcher but it did not work.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: By android launcher do u mean launcher APP or Your Launcher Activity ?  have u tried adding `android:resizeableActivity="false"` to `Activity` tag instead of `Application` tag?

Comment: @ADM I tried adding android:resizeableActivity="false" to Activity but it did not work